# Два header в одном файле

Tags: php

Такая проблема, что 2 header.

Задача, чтобы при входе менялся header.

Через php я вызываю второй header. C помощью include.

А первый header у меня прописан в index.php.

```
    <header class="header">
  <div>
    <?php include('navigation.php');
    ?>
  </header>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли что-то что удаляет default header?

Comment: Возможно лучше сделать `if` внутри navigation.php и проверять авторизован пользователь или нет и соответственно тот header и отдавать.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте один файл header.php, внутри него напишите проверку условия, по которому должен отдаваться тот или иной хидер. А сам файл включите в index.php и удалите html, который строит на всех страницах стандартный хидер

Answer (score 0):

Обязательно удалять? Можно через CSS например присвоить хеадерам разные классы и при входе скрывать первый

```
 .page_header{
    display:none;
 }
```